# window.location.href vs history.pushState - which to use?

Tags: javascript, window, react-router, browser-history

I've been teaching myself `react-router`, and now I'm wondering which method should be used for going to another page.

According to [this post (Programmatically navigate using react router)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router), you can go to another page by `this.props.history.push('/some/path')`.

Honestly, however, I'm not quite sure about the differences between `window.location.href` and `history.pushState`.

As far as I understand, `window.location.href = "/blah/blah";` leads you to anther page by making a new HTTP call, which refreshes the browser.

On the other hand, what `history.pushState` (and `this.props.history.push('/some/path')`) does is to **push a state**. This, apprently, changes HTTP referrer and consequently updates `XMLHttpRequest`.

Here is an excerpt from [mozila's documentation...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

> Using history.pushState() changes the referrer that gets used in the HTTP header for XMLHttpRequest objects created after you change the state.

To me, it sounds like both methods make a new HTTP call. If so, what are the differences?

Any advice will be appreciated.

**PS**

I thought that developers would need to consider whether it's necessary to get data from the server, before deciding how to go to another page.

If you need to retrieve data from the server, `window.location.href` would
be fine, since you'll make a new HTTP call. However, if you are using `<HashRouter>`, or you want to avoid refreshing you page for the sake of speed, what would be a good approach?

This question led me to make this post.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`history.pushstate` **does not** make a new HTTP call (from mozilla doc quoted by you):

> Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance after the user restarts the browser.

`window.location.href = "url"` navigates the browser to new location, so it **does** make a new http request. *Note: exception is the case when you specify new url as hash fragment. Then window is just scrolled to corresponding anchor*

---

You can check both running them from devTools console having Network tab open. Be sure to enable "preserve log" option. Network tab lists all new http requests.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, I'm still not 100% sure about Mozila's doc saying "history.pushState() changes the referrer that gets used in the HTTP header ". Is it fine to assume that changing the referrer in the HTTP header isn't to do with making a new HTTP call?

Comment: Another point of attention is the state of the application. When `history.push`is used the **state is maintained**. However, when `window.location.href` is used, the state **returns to the initial state**.

Comment: What if you want to make a new HTTP call (like a redirect) AND maintain the state?

Comment: @V.Rubinetti a new HTTP call means a new page and a new context; if you want to maintain the state you have to maintain the context or somehow pass it to the next page, for example by using query params.

Answer (score 4):

You can test this in the Network of your console. When using history with react router, no refresh is made within the app (no http request). You'd use this for a better UX flow and persistence of state. To my understanding, we're essentially modifying the url (without the http request) and react router uses pattern matching to render components according to this programmatic change.

Answer (score 0):

I use `browserHistory` in react-router v3. There is no refresh and the application state is maintained throughout.
To redirect, all I do is just `browserHistory.push('\componentPath')`, componentPath which is mapped in the routes config of the application.

So far had no issues , works like charm.
Hope this help.